# How to convert a std::string which contains '\0' to a char* array?

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a string like,

```
string str="aaa\0bbb";
```

and I want to copy the value of this string to a char* variable. I tried the following methods but none of them worked.

```
char *c=new char[7];

memcpy(c,&str[0],7);    // c="aaa"

memcpy(c,str.data(),7); // c="aaa"

strcpy(c,str.data());   // c="aaa"

str.copy(c,7);          // c="aaa"
```

How can I copy that string to a char* variable without loosing any data?.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `string str="aaa\0bbb";` does not pup `"bbb"` to `str`. You can try `string str("aaa\0bbb", 7);` instead.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C.

Comment: @WEB_UI: No, it isn't. That's what tags are for.

Comment: Your comment is correct. its a std:string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "aaa\0bbb", 7 );

    char *p = new char[s.size() + 1];

    std::memcpy( p, s.c_str(), s.size() );
    p[s.size()] = '\0';

    size_t n = std::strlen( p );

    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << p + n + 1  << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
aaa
bbb
```

You need to keep somewhere in the program the allocated memory size for the character array equal to `s.size() + 1`.

If there is no need to keep the "second part" of the object as a string then you may allocate memory of the size `s.size()` and not append it with the terminating zero.

In fact these methods used by you

```
memcpy(c,&str[0],7);    // c="aaa"

memcpy(c,str.data(),7); // c="aaa"

str.copy(c,7);          // c="aaa"
```

are correct. They copy exactly 7 characters provided that you are not going to append the resulted array with the terminating zero. The problem is that you are trying to output the resulted character array as a string and the used operators output only the characters before the embedded zero character.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider: (1) make sure that `str` already contains the complete literal (the constructor taking only a `char*` parameter might truncate at the string terminator char). (2) Provided that `str` actually contains the complete literal, statement `memcpy(c,str.data(),7)` should work. The only thing then is how you "view"  the result, because if you pass `c` to `printf` or `cout`, then they will stop printing once the first string terminating character is reached.

So: To make sure that your string literal `"aaa\0bbb"` gets completely copied into `str`, use `std::string str("aaa\0bbb",7)`; Then, try to print the contents of `c` in a loop, for example:

```
std::string str("aaa\0bbb",7);

const char *c = str.data();

for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
    printf("%c", c[i] ? c[i] : '0');
}
```

Comment: Your code printed out something like "aaa��0". It is not the same as str string.

Answer (score 0):

Your string consists of 3 characters. You may try to use

```
using namespace std::literals;
string str="aaa\0bbb"s;
```

to create string with \0 inside, it will consist of 7 characters

It's still won't help if you will use it as c-string (`(const) char*`). c-strings can't contain zero character.

Comment: @WEB_UI Not clear what you're talking about, but this works for strings of any length.

Comment: @WEB_UI Better methods for writing a literal? Very interesting.

Comment: @WEB_UI, I do not understand how regex (or your comments at all) are relevant to the question and/or answer

Comment: @WEB_UI: What are you talking about? Your comment is nonsense.

Comment: Just use a loop to map then print the string literal, much better than 're-defining' it. Here, see [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41926935/6368005)

Comment: @WEB_UI Please stop this nonsense.

Answer (score -1):

You already did (not really, see edit below). The problem however, is that whatever you are using to print the string (`printf`?), is using the c string convention of ending strings with a '\0'. So it starts reading your data, but when it gets to the `0` it will assume it is done (because it has no other way). 
If you want to simply write the buffer to the output, you will have to do this with something like

```
write(stdout, c, 7);
```

Now write has information about where the data ends, so it can write all of it. 
Note however that your terminal cannot really show a `\0` character, so it might show some weird symbol or nothing at all. If you are on linux you can pipe into hexdump to see what the binary output is.

EDIT:

Just realized, that your string also initalizes from `const char*` by reading until the zero. So you will also have to use a constructor to tell it to read past the zero:

```
std::string("data\0afterzero", 14);
```

(there are prettier solutions probably)